# Ryu SDN wsgi code error 400

Tags: python-2.7, wsgi, sdn, mininet, ryu

I have ubuntu both 14 and 16 running ryu sdn framework on a virtual box. i'm using python 2.7.12. I'm also using mininet to build my network. When i run an app using `./bin/ryu-manager ryu/app/simple_switch_rest_13.py` I get the following error message:

`127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017 19:23:47] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x04\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00A')
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017 19:23:47] "A" 400 -
(5633) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 43484)
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017 19:23:49] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x04\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00B')
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017 19:23:49] "B" 400 -
(5633) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 43486)
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017 19:23:51] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x04\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00C')
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017 19:23:51] "C" 400 -
(5633) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 43488)
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017 19:23:53] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x04\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00D')
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017 19:23:53] "D" 400 -
(5633) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 43494)
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jun/2017 19:23:55] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x04\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00E')`

It looks like something is incrementing... Just to be clear it does not affect the normal usage of the app. Its just a misleading error i supose....

**UPDATE:**
I found out that the switch is sending these messages to the controller. Could it be that i have diferent Openflow versions running? Enconding like utf-8 or something?

Answer (score 1):

Alrigth, so after a bit more of testing and research i found out that RYU controller uses port 6633 for openflow purposes and port 8080 for the REST server or wsgi app. So when you set `s1= net.addSwitch('s1',listenPort=6633)` instead of 8080 and the error messages went away.

Check it here: https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/doc/source/parameters.rst

Hope it helps anyone...